# Magento2 new theme is not displaying properly

Tags: magento2

I am using magento on my local host. For practice i download theme from [github](https://github.com/czone-tech/magento2-theme-fresh). But theme is not showing displaying properly. It look like css is broken. Here is [snapshot of theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgkTa.png).

I past code of theme under

> E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento\app\design\frontend\CzoneTech\fresh

Comment: It is not possible to answer WHY it happen with provided information but some possibilities are: 1. compile static files 2. if you are using nginx do you have properly configured vhost to serve static files? 3. do you have properly set permission bits?    Could you provide console log and network log? What are the response codes for static files?

Comment: @Bartosz Herba can you help me on teamviewer?

Comment: It seems to me that it could not load your assets. Are you sure they are generated? I would suggest you to use *Chrome DevTool*, and see the full path of assets if they are correct.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: @Bunyamin yes i have generated. Theme is not displaying properly in firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Magento version is 2.2. and that theme is not support with that.

Try with other theme.

Comment: How do you know his Magento version is 2.2?

Comment: Last time I did TeamViewer so I know

Comment: @Sunil Patel admin panel is not opening. I don't the reason.

Permission denied in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php on line 663

Error log record number: 366183775

Comment: Check that log file under var/log folder

Comment: There are 4 notepad files under var/log 

system, install, exception & debug

Answer (score 0):

Below you have the paths, from which you have to delete everything.

> E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/var/cache/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/var/page_cache/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/var/generation/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/var/di/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/var/session/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/var/tmp/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/var/view_preprocessed/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/pub/static/_requirejs/*
>       E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento/pub/static/frontend/*

Right-click on the `E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento` folder and click on `Properties`, and then at the bottom, you uncheck `Read Only` and click `Apply`

You must open a console **(terminal)**, but not in the browser console and run the commands below in this path `E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento` (root project):

```
E:\XAMPP\php bin/magento cache:clean
E:\XAMPP\php bin/magento cache:flush
E:\XAMPP\php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: now admin panel is not opening. showing an error Permission denied in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php on line 663

663 line code is :- $result = file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $ids)."\n", FILE_APPEND | ($this->_options['file_locking'] ? LOCK_EX : 0)) && $result;

how to solve this error?

Comment: Did you uncheck the `Read Only'`?